# Get T9 Trace Notification Window of the Keyboard

Tags: java, android-layout, android

I have an android application which could show keyboard when tapping the edit text. However, since the phone is new, it will display a T9 Trace notification when the keyboard shows up and this will trigger OnGlobalLayoutListener. My question is, is there any way I can get the T9 Trace notification dialog/window when the keyboard shows up?  Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the keyboard is changable on Android, you can never assume anything about how it looks or acts.  So no, there's no way to know if/when it will popup a window or to prevent it from doing so.  And even if you did, it wouldn't work for any other keyboard.